# How to convert from text file to sequence file?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a large .txt file of records that I need to convert into a (hadoop) sequence format for efficiency. I have found some answers to this online (such as [How to convert .txt file to Hadoop's sequence file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377118/how-to-convert-txt-file-to-hadoops-sequence-file-format)), but I'm new to hadoop and don't really understand them. If you could explain these a little more, or if you have another solution, that'd be great. If it helps, the records are separated by line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want the line to be tokenized into a Key and Value? (Typically the Key is a line number and the Value is the line text)

Comment: Like you said. Key:line number, Value:line text.

Comment: In the answer you have linked to, which specific part did you not understand or want more clarification on?

Comment: Normally the key is the byte offset and the value is the line of text, just to clarify.

Comment: Well, the top answer looked pretty complete, so that was what I tried first. At the top of the code I added import statements, but when I compile I get errors. I think some of the code is deprecated. The second answer seemed simpler, but incomplete. Again, I'm brand new to hadoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you were new to hadoop, do you know the basic idea of `Mapper` and `Reducer`? Both of them have KEY_IN_CLASS, VALUE_IN_CLASS, KEY_OUT_CLASS, VALUE_OUT_CLASS, so in your case, you can simple use mapper to do the convert,

for KEY_IN_CLASS, you can use the default `LongWritable`,

VALUE_IN_CLASS you need to use `Text`, since `Text` class deals with text input.

For KEY_OUT_CLASS, you can use `NullWritable`, it's a null key if you don't have a specific key.

For VALUE_OUT_CLASS, use `SequenceFileOutputFormat`.

I believe in order to use `SequenceFileOutputFormat`, you need to tell SequenceFileOutputFormat what key class and value class you use.