# Creating Sequence File Format for Hadoop MR

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I was working with `Hadoop MapRedue`, and had a question.
Currently, my mapper's `input KV type` is `LongWritable, LongWritable type` and 
`output KV type` is also `LongWritable, LongWritable type`.
InputFileFormat is SequenceFileInputFormat.
Basically What I want to do is to change a txt file into SequenceFileFormat so that I can use this into my mapper.

What I would like to do is

input file is something like this

`1\t2     (key = 1, value = 2)`

`2\t3     (key = 2, value = 3)`

and on and on...

I looked at this thread [How to convert .txt file to Hadoop's sequence file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377118/how-to-convert-txt-file-to-hadoops-sequence-file-format) but reliazing that `TextInputFormat` only support `Key = LongWritable and Value = Text`

Is there any way to get txt and make a sequence file in `KV = LongWritable, LongWritable`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, basically the same way I told in the other thread you've linked. But you have to implement your own `Mapper`.

Just a quick scratch for you:

```
public class LongLongMapper extends
    Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, LongWritable> {

  @Override
  protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
      Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, LongWritable>.Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    // assuming that your line contains key and value separated by \t
    String[] split = value.toString().split("\t");

    context.write(new LongWritable(Long.valueOf(split[0])), new LongWritable(
        Long.valueOf(split[1])));

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
      InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJobName("Convert Text");
    job.setJarByClass(LongLongMapper.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);

    // increase if you need sorting or a special number of files
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

    job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/input"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/output"));

    // submit and wait for completion
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
  }
}
```

Each value in your mapper function will get a line of your input, so we are just splitting it by your delimiter (tab) and parsing each part of it into longs.

That's it.

Comment: thank you, got lots of ideas from the skeleton, and was able to create a seq. file writer.

Comment: if you have an another example please send me so i can understand it more better, email id ashishwinoria@gmail.com, Thanks in advance dear

Comment: And please tell me what will be the reducer class input output format, i  mean Key and value for input and output