# Serializing Java object using Hadoop libraries

Tags: java, hadoop, serialization, mapreduce

I'm trying to serialize an object in Java and write it to a file so that my Map function can take that from the file and deserialize it to get the object back.

I am of the opinion that Java serialization isn't very optimal. So I want to use hadoop libraries to do this.

Could someone share with me some syntax of how that can be done. I'm very new to hadoop and don't know where to start. Some explanation of the code would be great too!

Comment: Which serializer do you want to use ... Avro, Sequence, Parquet, ????

Comment: wow, there are 3 of them! I don't know. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: http://inquidia.com/news-and-info/hadoop-file-formats-its-not-just-csv-anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serilization in Hadoop is done using Avro, Parquet, Sequence File, ORC e.t.c ... You can use any of the above in your java program. You need to understand that hadoop uses one of the above serilization formats. So you dont need those Hadoop Libraries.

Comment: I'm making a crawler and indexer for my search engine and want to create the inverted index to match any word to a list of documents. For that I have a map-reduce job which reads hadoop files containing serialized objects which are like:

object{
      String content_of_html_page;
      long document_id;
      }

Although evolution isn't much of an issue right now, I'd still like to consider it.

I'm using amazon S3 to store these files. Can I store these file types in S3? The article was an interesting read!
Which would you recommend I use for my purpose?

Comment: I'd also like to store a lot of these in one file. e.g.
serial object1
serial object2
serial object3 ...

Comment: Yes you can do that ... https://hadooptutorial.info/avro-serializing-and-deserializing-example-java-api/ follow this..

Answer (score 0):

You should use Hadoop serialization so that any InputFormat of your mapreduce job would read input records.

I advice you to follow the below steps,

> 1. Try to convert your java object as any of **Writable** implementation of
>      Mapreduce such as Text , IntWritable, ListWritable, etc. If not
>      feasible make your Java object to extend Writable interface of
>      hadoop and implement the custom read/write methods.
> 2. Use **SequenceFile** as the storage format, and create a Java program to use **SequenceFile.Writer** to write your above Writable objects into
>      a sequence file. Refer SequenceFile topic of Hadoop I/O chapter in
>      Hadoop definitive guide book.
> 3. Now write a mapreduce program with **SequenceFileInputFormat** as input
>      format and you will be getting the serialized java objects
>              read one by one in your mapper.

To create custom writable , refer

http://www.ashishpaliwal.com/blog/2012/05/hadoop-recipe-implementing-custom-writable/

To write writable objects to sequence file, refer,

[How to convert .txt file to Hadoop's sequence file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377118/how-to-convert-txt-file-to-hadoops-sequence-file-format)